# How to deal with the hang threads when using the Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100)

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Suppose we create the 100 threads by the code `ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100)` suppose unfortunately  all of the 100 threads hang ,in that case there is no free threads from the thread pool can be used, and no new request can be serviced.   so how to deal with such situation? Forcing abort the hang threads and let it return back to thread pool? If it is how to force aborting the threads? or if there is a timeout can be used , after the timeout the hang threads would abort automatically, and return back to thread pool?

Comment: Is this an XY problem? Do you know why the threads are hanging?

Comment: Agree with @bradimus, the solution is to not write code that hangs.  Most blocking operations in Java have timeout versions of methods (see, for ex. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect(java.net.SocketAddress) vs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect(java.net.SocketAddress,%20int) ).  Whether the work were happening in a thread pool or the main thread, you should generally use the timeout-able versions of methods.

Comment: you can shutdown the thread pool :-)

Comment: I think you may have a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html there are things like:  `ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy` and `setKeepAliveTime(TimeUnit t)`

Comment: Fixing code that leads to the situation looks like the best choice.

Comment: @bradimus , suppose there is a blocking issue happens at database, we need to deal with that situation.

Comment: Use circuit breakers - Don't start more tasks when you have detected an error situation.

Answer (score 0):

A thread has just one life, that's why Executor Service threads never die. Timeout is not an option here. You should have a timeout in the implementation that you've done. This can be done only if it's hanging because of usage of some external service like database or http service. Apart from that you've to ensure that thread lock isn't happening in your local code. Use profilers to figure out these problems.

Comment: Yes,suppose there is a blocking issue happens at database, and we don't want the thread hang over some period, so we need to kill it.

Comment: No.. You shouldn't kill the thread. You should set appropriate timeout for database connections. If timeout is defaulted to a higher value, that thread will take longer to finish.
If due to some other reason as I mentioned above, you have to do what I mentioned/suggested above. Last thing is to restart your application if all threads are irrecoverable and fix the issues that you had.

Comment: ,Yes, for the database we can set the timeout, so how about if there is no way to set the timeout for the other external data source.?

Comment: There's always some way to set a timeout for any kind of external services. Fatal problems come when there's a problem with some internal implication that's consuming or locking the same thread.